# How to force deployment through CI server in Azure?

Tags: azure, svn, teamcity

We currently have this architecture :

- production servers with limited access
- Subversion server where developpers can commit
- Teamcity server that build the websites from SVN and deploy it to the production server

The purpose is to make it impossible to deploy a website without commiting the code to the appropriate branch. And it's working very well.

Now we're moving some stuff to azure. And I don't want to put my publish profile in the project because if I do so any one can publish from his visual studio instance.

I thought about this : create publish profiles from the azure account, upload them to the CI server and passe an absolute path to the publishprofile msbuild parameter.

Do you think there is a cleaner way to do this : I'd prefer to do the profile uploading directly in teamcity.

Comment: Did you ever find out more information on this?

Comment: Nope nothing, just telling everyone to be serious and breaking an arm when someone deploys from his machine. (but frankly, deployment from teamcity is really way easier than with visualstudio)

Comment: What I've found is that you don't need to include the production publish profiles in the visual studio project, however you might want to keep around the local publish profiles for emulation. I plan to use TFS for my builds, but TeamCity would work too.